# How to show negative numbers as positive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have $http.Get data from server. i have a function to get the total value. it is working fine, the total value is negative(-370). but when i am using it to make angular chart i need to display as a positive number. any one can help me?

```
 Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
        total += parseInt(this[i][prop])
    }
    return total
}
$scope.totalCreadit = function (arr) {
    return arr.sum("credits");  
}
```

thanks in advance!!.

Comment: um https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs

Answer (score 1):

In the sum function, get the [absolute value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) of the total amount before returning the value:

```
return Math.abs(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Math.abs() function
`Math.abs(number)`

Answer (score 0):

you need

> Math.abs(this[i][prop]);